# Angular 2 - JSON.stringify() object to show in ag-grid

Tags: json, angular, object, stringify

I have ag-grid and from service I get data that i show in grid like this:

My ts code looks like this:

```
constructor( private codeService: CodeService ) {
        this.columnDefs = [
                 { headerName: "Name", field: "name"},
                 { headerName: "Property", field: "properties", editable: true },
                            ];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.codeService.getCodeType( this.name ).subscribe(
                response => { this.handleSuccess( response ); },
                error => { console.error( error ); });

    }

    handleSuccess( aaTypes ) {
        var data = [];
        aaTypes.forEach( ( aaType ) => {
            var entriesForType = [];
            entriesForType.push( aaType );    
                if ( entriesForType.length > 0 ) {
                    entriesForType.forEach( entry => data.push( entry ) );
                    this.data = data;
                    if(this.gridOptions.api !== null){
                        this.gridOptions.api.setRowData( data );
                    }
                } 
        });
    }
```

As you can see... properties are actually object and it shows like that in grid on picture one ...My question is, is there any way for me to stringify that "properties" so it will show like string and not object.. Im ok if it shows something like "{location: 0, color; 255}".

Comment: did you try this https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0

Comment: I have seen this, but I don't quite understand how can I apply in my case, but it seem that this is just what I need. @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a valueFormatter to your columnDefs and create the formatter:

```
constructor( private codeService: CodeService ) {
    this.columnDefs = [
             { headerName: "Name", field: "name"},
             { headerName: "Property", field: "properties", valueFormatter: jsonFormatter, editable: true },
                        ];
}

function jsonFormatter(d) {
     return JSON.stringify(d);
}
```